# Intersections of completions of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Say we have a number field $K$ in which the rational prime $2$ splits like this
$$(2)\mathcal{O}_K:=\mathfrak{P}_1\mathfrak{P}_2
.$$

I am wondering what is $K_{\mathfrak{P}_1}\cap K_{\mathfrak{P}_2}$. Where $K_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ is the completion of $K$ at the prime $\mathfrak{P}_i$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Before asking what $K_{\mathfrak{P}_1}\cap K_{\mathfrak{P}_2}$ is, one should say how to define this intersection. Is this intersection well defined?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to define it, I guess that if I have a sequence $(x_n)\subset K$ which is Cauchy with respect to both the metric induced by $| \:\: |_{\mathfrak{P}_1}$ and $| \:\: |_{\mathfrak{P}_2}$, it has to be convergent to the same thing? I am quite confused about it, any help would be appreciated! @Crostul

Comment: @Crostul Both are algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$ so one can probably take the intersection within a choice of $\overline{\mathbb Q}_2$

Comment: Will the intersection be only $\mathbb{Q}_2$, @KentaS?

Comment: One definition you could use for the intersection of two field extensions, is (assuming it exists) the maximal subfield of $K_{\mathfrak{P}_1}$ that is isomorphic to a subfield of $K_{\mathfrak{P}_2}$. Or perhaps some equivalence class of such subfields. Of course this might give weird answers and doesn't satisfy some intuitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question makes no sense as written, because those completions are not initially inside a common larger field.  And putting them into one might make the answer depend on the choice of embeddings into the larger common field.

It's like taking two finite extensions of a field $F$ and asking for their intersection. Unless the fields are already presented inside a common larger field, there is no intersection.

Suppose I say $\alpha^4 = 2$ and $\beta^4 = 2$ in fields of characteristic $0$, and I want to know $\mathbf Q(\alpha) \cap \mathbf Q(\beta)$. The question has no answer because I haven't given you a larger field containing these so that you can decide what lies in both of them.  Inside $\mathbf C$, if $\beta = \pm \alpha$ then the fields are equal and their intersection is the full fields, while if $\beta \not= \pm \alpha$ then the intersection is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$. The exact same kind of answer could be given if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_2$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to say with my comment. Excellent answer.